# getting value from Timer0 AVR

Tags: timer, avr, avr-studio4

I am currently writing a program in AVR Studio 4 in which i would like to use the Timer to get a random number.

I can get the timer to run, however i do not know how to get the current value of the timer. In general can the value be stored in a register or is it not accessible.

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Don't worry got it sorted. I managed to figure out that my program never got past 1 and managed to figure out how to store the values.